# Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) won't validate Archive

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Xcode won't allow me to validate my archive in the Organizer. Originally, I was on 8.3 (beta), so understandably it gave me this error message.  But I downloaded version 8, (presumably not beta) and I get the exact same message.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you on a macOS sierra beta-version? Both mac os *and* xcode must be release versions.

Comment: I'm on sierra.  I was not aware of the concept of a release version for the OS relating to Xcode.  I'm on Sierra 10.2